# Variables in Create Statement

Tags: sql, mysql, variables, connection, federated

I am trying to use some variables in a creation script for database setups. I am not exactly sure how to use them. Please explain how to properly format my code. Below is the code I try, and the error I get:

```
SET @username = 'xxxx'; -- store number goes here
SET @password = 'xxxxxx'; -- store password goes here

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`release_date` datetime,
`front_image_file` varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED  
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
CONNECTION='mysql://`@username`:`@password`@host_name:3306/database_name/table_tame' ;
```

error

```
#1432 - Can't create federated table. The data source connection string 'mysql://`@username`:`@password`@host_name:3306/databa' is not in the correct format
```

I also tried it without the `

Trying EdmundG's solution

```
SET @username = 'xxxx'; -- store number goes here
SET @password = 'xxxxxx'; -- store password goes here

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`release_date` datetime,
`front_image_file` varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED  
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
CONNECTION='Uid=@username; Pwd=@password; Server=****; Port=3306; Database =****; Table=****;' ;
```

didn't work, still says not formatted correctly

Answer (score 6):

MySQL doesn't support variable interpolation directly into syntax like that.

You could, however, build a string with those variables and then prepare and execute it as [dynamic SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```
SET @username = 'xxxx'; -- store number goes here
SET @password = 'xxxxxx'; -- store password goes here

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (',
    '  `id` int(11) auto_increment,',
    '  `release_date` datetime,',
    '  `front_image_file` varchar(255),',
    '  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)',
    ') ENGINE=FEDERATED',
    ' DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1', 
    ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1', 
    ' CONNECTION=''mysql://', @username, ':', @password, 
    '@host_name:3306/database_name/table_tame');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK third try.

There are two possible problems I can see.

1. You have right quotes instead of
   generic single quotes in your SQL.
2. You need to define the variables
   and execute before running the SQL
   that uses those variables.

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: I got the connection string from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html and it works fine when I don't have the variables in there. If you could put the whole thing together for me that would be awesome

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work. Wouldn't you have to wrap the entire command in a string and use an EXEC call?

Comment: Of course, that comment is coming from someone in the SqlServer world; perhaps it's different in MySQL.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '& @username & ':' & @password' at line 9

Comment: It should work without an exec however, sometimes you need to declare the variables, execute that statement, before you can use the variables.  In SQL Server you use GO, not sure what the MySQL equivalent is.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql is for connections strings in ADO.NET and have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 5+ could you try placing it in a stored function, and then running the function?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this. mysql doesn't parse DDL statements for variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

SET @username   = 'xxxx';-- store number goes here

SET @password   = 'xxxxxx';-- store password goes here

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
release_date datetime,
front_image_file varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY  (id))
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 CONNECTION='Uid='+@username'; Pwd='+@password+'; Server=****; Port=3306; Database =****';
```